# Are there any known differences between einsum in python2 vs. python3?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, tensorflow, numpy-einsum

Are there any known differences between einsum in Python2 and Python3?

https://github.com/tscohen/GrouPy
I was trying to run the code for Tensorflow here, and get a mismatch

File "/home/----/.conda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/einsumfunc.py", line 710, in einsum_path
    "not match previous terms.", char, tnum)
ValueError: ("Size of label '%s' for operand %d does not match previous terms.", 'h', 1)

in Python 3.6, but not when I run the same code in Python 2.7

Comment: There have been changes with recent numpy versions.  1.14 is the latest.

Comment: I had version 1.14.1 in my Python2.7 environment and 1.14.0 in my 3.6 environment. It seems that this fixed it. Thank you!